# Application crashes on equalizeHist of OpenCV

Tags: c++, mfc, opencv

My MFC app runs various API from OpenCV2. Everything else is working fine. But when my program runs

```
cv::Mat result;
cv::equalizeHist(m_cvImage,result);
```

I get following runtime exception.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7727fbae in OpenCVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0029e944..

"C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:2430: error: (-215) CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_ARE_TYPES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_MAT_TYPE(src->type) == CV_8UC1"
```

According to debugger, the exception was thrown in the middle of processing (about 40%) the image in equalizeHist. Is there anything I need to do? FYI: I am using binary OpenCV provided by its web site.

UPDATE:

I've resolved this issue by converting images to gray-level before equalizing it. I just didn't know

1. the function only works with gray-level image
2. images that look like gray-level can be non-gray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine the problem you are encountering is that `m_cvImage` is a 3-channel image. So, you need to convert it to a grayscale image before you can call `equalizeHist`.

```
cvtColor(m_cvImage, m_cvImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat result;
cv::equalizeHist(m_cvImage, result);
```

Also, have a look at the [EqualizeHist_Demo.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Histograms_Matching/EqualizeHist_Demo.cpp) tutorial sample to see how it is used.

Comment: Exactly. I hope you posted earlier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Paul I think you had updated your post as I was writing my answer :)